# export data from postgresql

Tags: postgresql, export

I have some text like xml -code in a field of table. I want to export the data from my field into file without any changes.

I've tried to use a lot of variants but all of them changes the text. The most successful variants were:

```
COPY (SELECT alll FROM super.a_a ) TO 'D:\alll.txt' CSV ;
```

But there appeared extra quotes "".

```
COPY (SELECT alll FROM super.a_a ) TO 'D:\alll.txt CSV QUOTE ' ' ;
```

But there appeared extra spaces.

In my field I have such date like : name="firsname" and when I use any of varients I get something like that : name=""firstname"" or name=\n\r"firstname\n\r""

Comment: COPY is always tied to a format. For no format whatsoever, use SELECT and let your client software direct the results into a file.

Comment: Just remove `CSV` to export to the pure text format.

Comment: @Abelisto: No. In the non-CSV COPY format, backslashes are doubled and control characters are output as backslash-style sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can just execute the query in psql and redirect its output to a file after removing all headers. Did you try something like:

```
$ psql
user=> \o outputfile.txt
user=> \t on
user=> SELECT alll FROM super.a_a;
user=> \q
```